# Inheriting classes or multiply classes in R?

Tags: r, class, object

There appears an interesting situation in R S3 objects because they do not inherits classes.

One can see that `agnes.object` (result of `agnes{cluster}` function ) has 2 different classes.

```
library( cluster )
example( agnes )
class( agn1 )
[1] "agnes" "twins"
```

But meantime when you read `agnes.object` [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/cluster/html/agnes.object.html) there is a section INHERITANCE and there there is a sentence: 'The class "agnes" inherits from "twins".'

What do you think about that? Is it really inheritance or just multiply classes :)?

Answer (score 1):

S3 allows a linear hierarchy of classes. So

```
> class(agn1)
[1] "agnes" "twins"
```

says that agn1 is an instance of class agnes, which extends (inherits from) twins. Here we define generics and methods

```
## S3 generics
foo <- function(x) UseMethod("foo")
bar <- function(x) UseMethod("bar")
baz <- function(x) UseMethod("baz")

## S3 methods -- append '.' and class name
foo.twins = function(x) "twins"
foo.agnes = function(x) "agnes"
bar.twins = function(x) "twins"
baz.agnes = function(x) "agnes"
```

and illustrate inheritance in dispatch (method selection).

```
> foo(agn1)
[1] "agnes"
> bar(agn1)
[1] "twins"
> baz(agn1)
[1] "agnes"
```

The S3 class system in R is instance-based, there is no formal class definition. The class inheritance is implied by the character vector. So an object with class `"agnes"` has no parent class, whereas a class `c("agnes", "twins")` defines a linear class hierarchy with parent `"twins"` (even if there is no object anywhere with class `"twins"` alone!). Because there is no formal class definition, two objects declaring themselves to be of the same class could have completely different structure, e.g.,

```
structure(list(), class="A")
structure(list(x=1, y=2, z=3), class="A")
```

can both legitimately claim to be of class "A"!

Comment: But if a function is overloaded for class twins only, and there is somehow an object with only one class "agnes", then this function will not work on that object. So it looks like "agnes" does Not really inherits after twins. My question only showed that if there is an object with 2 classes the function takes one or Another class in linear order

Comment: inheritance is implied by the character vector; if the vector is of length one and the single value is 'agnes', then that says that that instance does not have any inheritance relationship. S3 is instance-based -- the inheritance is implied by the class vector, not by some class definition.

Comment: So does it mean there is a mistake in agnes.object manual :)? It should be written that agnes.object is of 2 classess :) ?